# using 'like' to find whole words in sql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, regex, t-sql, sql-like

I have a search routine that works in transact-sql (Microsoft's version), it does something to similar to:

```
search * from mytable
where ' ' + title + ' ' like ' %white% '
```

My goal is to find words but not subwords.  I don't want to find "`whitener`", I just to find titles that contain white.

This kind of search does not work in MySQL though.  MySQL has the '`like`' operator, but something about it must be different.

So my question, is, is there a general way of doing this that works in both t-sql and MySQL.

Comment: I'm not sure but might `like '% white %'` work?

Comment: If you don't mind using a function which replaces all the non-letter characters with, say, '.' in a string and adds '.' to the beginning and the end, then you can use like '%.white.%'.

Comment: how about trying `select * from mytable where title like '% %white% %'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your T-SQL query won’t work as posted. I had to modify it to obtain the
desired results:

```
select * from mytable
where ' ' + title + ' ' like '% white %'
```

Note the order of the spaces and percentage wildcards within the single
quotes. Also it’s `SELECT` not `SEARCH`.

To get it working in MySQL, the query needs to be rewritten as:

```
select * from mytable
where concat(' ', title, ' ') like '% white %';
```

MySQL uses the `CONCAT()` function to implement string concatenation while
T-SQL traditionally uses plus sign, `+` to implement string concatenation.

MS SQL server has supported the [CONCAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)
function since *SQL Server 2012* so if you’re using a recent version, this
second query should be the only one you need. Otherwise, I don’t think there’s
a simple version which will work with both types of DBMS.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this in MySQL with:

```
search * 
from mytable
where concat(' ',  title , ' ') like '% white %'
```

Do note that your `like` pattern should have the wildcards as the first and last characters, not spaces.

This formulation will work in SQL Server 2012+.  `LIKE` (along with the wildcards) is standard SQL and available in both databases.  `CONCAT()` is also standard SQL, but not available in SQL Server prior to SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as following:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE title regexp '[[:<:]]white[[:>:]]';
```

This is a regular expression way to find against exact string.